# How to import SASS stylesheet and apply them only to a particular element?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, frontend

I have the following code

```
@import '~bulma'
```

In Webpack this means that I’m just importing whatever SASS the `@import` statement points to. In this case, it’s a pretty deep set of styles.

I would like to apply this only to the children of a particular container:

```
<div class="apply-bulma-here">...</div>
```

The children can be arbitrarily complex.

The first thing I tried is this:

```
.apply-bulma-here >
  @import '~bulma'
```

This seems to work on simple JSFiddles but in my code it doesn’t seem to work completely. I suspect that after some depth in the SASS files the styles aren’t picked up anymore.

**Is this the right approach? Is there a quick way to scope the import only to the descendants of one particular element?**

By looking at the compile code it seems that every single rule is prefixed with the additional condition `.apply-bulma-here>` which sounds about right. So I don’t understand why it would behave differently.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `.apply-bulma-here { @import '~bulma' }`?

Comment: If I do that it seems to work, except `.apply-bulma-here header { font-family: monospace }` and similar rules don’t get applied. Weird!

Comment: Sorry it was `.apply-bulma-here body` Doh! Thanks you solved it.